# What GIS software is used by web maps sites (Google, Bing Maps, etc)?

Tags: web-mapping, software-recommendations

We all have seen beatiful (imo) maps produced by [Google](https://maps.google.se/) and [Microsoft](http://www.bing.com/maps/). There are many others; some of them are of global use (such as [MapQuest](http://www.mapquest.com/), [TomTom](http://routes.tomtom.com) or [HERE](http://here.com)), and some are just of country scale.

I assume that these companies have obtained/collected/bought raw vector data and then have used a GIS software package and some custom cartography workflows to produce maps with good symbology/layout and then cached them into multiple tiles.

Rasterizing vectors into tiles is not that particularly interesting, but I was often wondering what kind of Desktop GIS software have those large companies used to make those maps? Esri, for instance, uses ArcGIS platform for making the Esri basemaps such as [Esri World Street Map](http://www.arcgis.com/home/webmap/viewer.html?webmap=7990d7ea55204450b8110d57e20c99ab).

What desktop GIS software do Google and Microsoft use for creating maps? I am curious about that because I want to know what other GIS packages apart from Esri ArcGIS are capable of doing this work on such a large scale.

Comment: As it stands I think this question is too broad because it is effectively asking the same question for each of 5 (or more) web map sites.  I recommend that you focus it down to the one that you most want to know about and then research/ask about the others separately.

Comment: You are probably right. I have specified just two - Google and MS.

Comment: I think that will still lead to two sets of Answers or double-barrelled Answers rather than a clean Q&A.

Comment: Pretty sure Google uses their own custom software for just about everything. Microsoft might be using some ESRI stuff, but probably mostly custom as well.

Comment: @blah238, ah, I was suspecting that but couldn't imagine writing a decent desktop GIS package when there are some good ones already available. Seems as MS and Google have put a lot of time on just developing this GIS package.

Comment: For their specialized needs a consumer-oriented desktop GIS package wouldn't cut it, and when you have large budgets and software development expertise it is likely much more effective to write your own software.

Comment: @blah238, great point, agreed.

Comment: I would just like to remind everyone that this site is about problems: our [introductory pages](http://gis.stackexchange.com/about) request that you "Focus on questions about an actual problem you have faced." In its present state this post only seems intended to elicit discussion. Alex, could you please edit your question to exhibit a particular problem that we could address?

Comment: @whuber, I completely understand what you mean, but thought it might be interesting for others too to figure out how web mapping sites are actually produced. There are dozens of top questions that do not address any specific problem that needs to be solved: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions?sort=votes. I have updated my question to make it sound more problem oriented, hope it looks better now!

Comment: I think the question is relevant because although the average GIS practicioner might never actually work on a worldwide web mapping system like Google Maps, they will undoubtedly be faced with questions like "why can't you just make it like Google Maps?" Being armed with some knowledge of what actually goes into creating such a product helps to manage expectations from customers who make unreasonable demands :)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Google use a self-developed tool called *Atlas* to maintain geodata.

In this [video from Google I/O 2013](https://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_detailpage&v=FsbLEtS0uls) you see how *Atlas* works (*Atlas* starts at 7:30 - but it is interesting to see the whole video).

Comment: Jump to 7 minutes and 29 seconds for slides http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FsbLEtS0uls#t=449

Answer (score 14):

You didn't specifically ask about any open source tools or data in your original post, but OpenStreetMap has a global web map that is as good as the ones from Google or Bing. Because it is open source, there are lots of great resources explaining how they manage their data and render their map.

If you want to create a worldwide map like Google or Bing, you can use OpenStreetMap data and their open source tools to do it. You'd store your data in PostgreSQL/PostGIS, render map tiles using Mapnik, and serve those map tiles on the web using something like Apache and mod_tile. Any web page that wanted to include your map could do it with OpenLayers or Leaflet (which take the place of something like Google Maps API).

[Switch2OSM](http://switch2osm.org/) has some good instructions for how you would go about setting up your own global map.

Comment: LOVE that you added osm.